# Getting “No column was specified for column 1" when joining a derived table

Tags: sql-server, join

I am writing a `left join` and getting a

> No column was specified for column 1" error.

What am I doing wrong?

```
LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT  CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN '' ELSE mycolumn END
   FROM 
    (
        SELECT code_value 
        FROM allocation 
        WHERE allocation.id='[val]'
        GROUP BY code_value
    ) grp
   GROUP BY code_value
) AS code4table
ON code4table.itemid = table1.id
```

I want to return code_value value if all values are same else return ''. I am guessing I also need to include the `code4table.itemid` in my select query but not sure how.

Comment: @Mithil: "SQL" is **not** a DBMS product. It's *query language". Postgres, Oracle, Firebird, DB2.... they all use "SQL". We can see that you are using SQL because of the code you posted. But we need to know which DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In addition to an alias for the derived table (`ALIASTABLE`), you need a column alias (`ALIASCOLUMN` below) for the computed column:

```
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT  CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN '' ELSE mycolumn END AS ALIASCOLUMN
   FROM
   ...
) AS ALIASTABLE
ON ALIASTABLE.ALIASCOLUMN = outertable.column
```

In your case `ALIASCOLUMN` name should be `itemid` in order to match the outer join naming.

(Because you are deriving a new column with the case / when, even though you have a named column `mycolumn` in the `ELSE`, Sql won't default the derived column name to this). If it makes sense to do so, you can retain the same column name (`mycolumn`) and change the final `ON` to match.